# How to filter part of lines after grepping it

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I have section in files of the format

```
**> ### UPDATE `cams`.`product_external_content`
> ### WHERE
> ###   @1=330904786 /* INT meta=0 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
> ###   @2=124754078 /* INT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
> ###   @3='main' /* VARSTRING(135) meta=135 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
> ###   @4='imgs/a/b/c/sdtv/1028860-26.jpg' /* VARSTRING(900) meta=900 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
> ###   @5='main' /* VARSTRING(135) meta=135 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
> --
> --
> ###   @10='2019-06-17 15:27:03' /* DATETIME(0) meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
> ### SET
> ###   @1=330904786 /* INT meta=0 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
> ###   @2=124754078 /* INT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
> ###   @3='main' /* VARSTRING(135) meta=135 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
> ###   @4='imgs/a/b/c/sdtv/SDL999436767-26.jpg' /* VARSTRING(900) meta=900 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
> ###   @5='main' /* VARSTRING(135) meta=135 nullable=1 is_null=0 */**
```

I want to grep by @2=(id) and get the corresponding @1= and @4= data.
How can I do that ?

I have tried grep '@2=124754078' bin.sql -C 3 to get the lines before and after it but don't know how to further filter the lines.

I want the output for sample in the question like
@2=139358291 @1=330903701 @4=imgs/a/b/c/sdtv/SDL018872305-26.jpg

Comment: `grep -Eo '@[124][^ ]+'`

Comment: How can you define section boundaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F"['= ]+" '
    { val = $3 "=" $4 }
    /@1=/ { f1 = val }
    /@2=/ { f2 = ($4=="124754078" ? val : "") }
    /@4=/ && (f2!="") { print f1 ORS f2 ORS val ORS }
' file
@1=330904786
@2=124754078
@4=imgs/a/b/c/sdtv/1028860-26.jpg

@1=330904786
@2=124754078
@4=imgs/a/b/c/sdtv/SDL999436767-26.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that I used was this

```
for word in $(cat file.txt); do  grep 'product_external_content' -A5 bin.sql | grep -A3 -B1 "@2=${word}" |grep "@1\|@4" |awk -F '=' '{print $2}'|awk '{print $1}'; done  > data.txt
```

Comment: That contains several bugs and anti-patterns. Don't do it. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001, http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219, and you never need grep when you're using awk and certainly not a pipeline of 3 greps plus 2 awks!

Comment: I will look into it. I am a rookie at bash and these commands so not aware of the good practices. Thanks for pointing it out